# JAXBContext Unmarshall XML string with multiple rootElement

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Below is my XML string, I got problem to accessing Entity3 list.

```
<Entity1>
  <field1>Value1</field1>
  <field2>Value2</field2>
  <Entity2>
     <field3>Value1</field3>
     <field4>Value2</field4>
  </Entity2>
  <Entity3s>
    <Entity3List>
       <Entity3>
          <field5>Value1</field5>
          <field6>Value2</field6>
       </Entity3>
       <Entity3>
          <field5>Value1</field5>
          <field6>Value2</field6>
       </Entity3>
    </Entity3List>
  </Entity3s> 
</Entity1>
```

Below is my java object class

**Entity**

```
@XmlRootElement(name= "Entity")
public class Entity {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    private String field3;
    private String field4;

    private List<Entity3> entity3s;
}
```

**Entity2**

```
public class Entity2 {
    private String field3;
    private String field4;
}
```

**Entity3**

```
public class Entity3 {
    private String field5;
    private String field6;
}
```

How should I annotate the Entity3 list because it is wrapped by two root element `<Entity3s>` and `<Entity3List>`

```
jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Entity1.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Entity1 entity1= (Entity1) unmarshaller.unmarshal(sr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these classes

**Entity1**

```
@XmlRootElement(name= "Entity1")
public class Entity {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private Entity2 entity2;
    private Entity3s entity3s;

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

    public void setField2(String field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Entity2")
    public Entity2 getEntity2() {
        return entity2;
    }

    public void setEntity2(Entity2 entity2) {
        this.entity2 = entity2;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Entity3s")
    public Entity3s getEntity3s() {
        return entity3s;
    }

    public void setEntity3s(Entity3s entity3s) {
        this.entity3s = entity3s;
    }

}
```

**Entity2**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Entity2 {
    private String field3;
    public String getField3() {
        return field3;
    }
    public void setField3(String field3) {
        this.field3 = field3;
    }
    public String getField4() {
        return field4;
    }
    public void setField4(String field4) {
        this.field4 = field4;
    }
    private String field4;
}
```

**Entity3s**

```
public class Entity3s {

    private Entity3List entity3List;

    @XmlElement(name = "Entity3List")
    public Entity3List getEntity3List() {
        return entity3List;
    }

    public void setEntity3List(Entity3List entity3List) {
        this.entity3List = entity3List;
    }


}
```

**Entity3List**

```
public class Entity3List {
    private List<Entity3> entity3s;

    @XmlElement(name = "Entity3")
    public List<Entity3> getEntity3s() {
        return entity3s;
    }

    public void setEntity3s(List<Entity3> entity3s) {
        this.entity3s = entity3s;
    }

}
```

**Entity3**

```
public class Entity3 {
    private String field5;
    private String field6;
    public String getField5() {
        return field5;
    }
    public void setField5(String field5) {
        this.field5 = field5;
    }
    public String getField6() {
        return field6;
    }
    public void setField6(String field6) {
        this.field6 = field6;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which mean if the tag is redundant I also need to create one class for it.